# How to initialise the calendar with blank date in tkcalendar?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I'm trying to create a date picker. I found a code online that works for me. However, with this code, the program shows today's date as default when it starts like this:

[image]

Is there a way to set the default date to blank like this?

[image]

I have been looking for an answer but no luck.

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk

from tkcalendar import DateEntry

from datetime import date

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(root)

style.theme_use('clam')


class MyDateEntry(DateEntry):

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):

        DateEntry.__init__(self, master=None, **kw)

        self._top_cal.configure(bg='black', bd=1)


de = MyDateEntry(root,selectbackground='gray80',
                 selectforeground='black',
                 normalbackground='white',
                 normalforeground='black',
                 background='gray90',
                 foreground='black',
                 bordercolor='gray90',
                 othermonthforeground='gray50',
                 othermonthbackground='white',
                 othermonthweforeground='gray50',
                 othermonthwebackground='white',
                 weekendbackground='white',
                 weekendforeground='black',
                 headersbackground='white',
                 headersforeground='gray70')

de.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateEntry` is inherited from `Entry` widget. So you can delete the content just like a normal `Entry` widget:

```
class MyDateEntry(DateEntry):

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):

        DateEntry.__init__(self, master=None, **kw)

        self._top_cal.configure(bg='black', bd=1)

        self.delete(0, "end")
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you very much :)

Comment: If it helped, consider accepting the answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I did not need to make a class. This solution works totally fine:

```
date_started = DateEntry(root, locale='en_US', date_pattern='yyyy-mm-dd')
date_started.delete(0, "end")  ## Only this line needed to be added to clear the field.
date_started.place(x=150, y=60, height=25, width=120)
```